# Could not attach to pid : “16541” unable to attach ios simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ios10

I have a sourcecode which is dependent on a framework which requires Base SDK 7.0. It is very old codebase, so I am using Xcode 6.4 still. Since iOS10 is released recently, found few issues in iOS10. But, couldn't debug or solve them since I couldn't run it in Xcode6. I downloaded Xcode8 and copied SDK in /Applications/Xcode8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs folder.

I can still see Base SDK iOS7.0 not found and I cannot run it in iOS10 simulator. I get **Could not attach to pid : “16541” unable to attach** this error when I try running in iPad Air (iOS 10) simulator.

Is there any other way, I can run it on iOS10 simulator? Or only way to work is update the dependent framework to latest SDK? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very not supported and will not work.  Xcode 6 is not compatible with the iOS 10 platforms.  Just install Xcode 8.

Comment: Thanks! 
I guess then Xcode8 will not support iOS7 has its Base SDK as well.